# how to pass a byte array from a CSharp client application to an ATL COM object

Tags: c#, c++, com, atl

I want to write an application with csharp which reads the content of a file and passes it to an ATL COM object.

I have a problem with IDL. I defined a method named "Decode" on an ATL-COM object like below:

```
[id(101), helpstring("Decode")] HRESULT Decode([in] BYTE* pBuff, [in] INT nLen, [out, retval] INT* pnRetVal);
```

But, when I compiled my own COM dll and wanted to use it in the CSharp application I found the method with this signature:

```
int MyClass.Decode(ref byte pBuff, int nLen);
```

But, I excepted to have a method like this:

```
    int MyClass.Decode(byte[] pBuff, int nLen);
```

Do you have any suggestions? I also tried different types such as VARIANT* or BYTE**, but I look for best solution.

Comment: Pointers to C arrays are not Automation compatible types.  They are indistinguishable from, in your case, a single byte passed by reference.  While IDL has a way to attribute the argument to indicate it is an array, type libraries don't have that ability.  Technically you can decompile the interop library and edit the method definition.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719715%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), you have to declare your function as taking a `SAFEARRAY(byte)` inside the IDL.

Also, passing a `VARIANT` (which shows as `object` in the C# side) will work, provided you extract the `SAFEARRAY` inside the C++ code.

Comment: I declared a function as taking a VARIANT* pdata in the idl and doign this :
pdata->bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"TOTO");
When I pass (from c#) a string "TUTU", "TUTU" is return, not "TOTO", which is not the attended behaviour according to the link you posted. Any idea ?

Comment: (Forgot to say that VARIANT* pdata is [in,out] in the idl.)